# ARkit, why i can't scale this node?

Tags: swift, xcode, scale, scenekit, arkit

I just started study ARkit, I managed to create an ARAnchor at the UItapGesture and inside the method of the delegate node for anchor or didAdd node for anchor I render and display the SCNcube or the SCNsphere .

example:

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            
            if let ancoraNome = anchor.name , ancoraNome == "sun" {
                debugPrint("did add anchor")
                let mesh = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
                mesh.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
                let nodo = SCNNode(geometry: mesh)
                node.scale = SCNVector3(10, 10, 10)
                node.addChildNode(nodo)
                
            } else {
                let mesh = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
                mesh.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
                let nodo = SCNNode(geometry: mesh)
                node.scale = SCNVector3(0, 10, 10)
                node.addChildNode(nodo)
            }
        }
```

why I can't scale up the node? for testing I set node.scale , but the object always keep his initial size of 20 cm for the box and 10 cm for the sphere..

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ARKit continuously changes the `transform` of the node associated to the anchor it manages and will thus override the node's `scale`. What you can do is create an extra node inserted as a child of `node` that will hold `mesh` and then set the `scale` on this node instead.